# Latex ignore subheaders

Tags: pdftex, subsection

Is there a way to get latex to ignore subsection headers below a certain level without commenting them out?

When I am drafting and editing documents, I like to put subsection headings down to the level of each paragraph. It helps me organize my thoughts. But when I generate my final document, I want to be able to remove all the subheadings without having to comment out each individual one. Is there an easy way to do this in the document header? I know it is possible to remove them from the table of contents, but I do not want them to show up in the document body either either.

Comment: Assuming you haven't used the stared form I guess you could write `\renewcommand{\subsection}[2][]{}` but it's difficult to say whether there will be any side effects without knowing what class you are using.

Comment: I'm using IEEEtran. Not seeing any issues with that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome To Tex.SE

There are really 2 options:

1. Redefine the Subsection Command: In your document's preamble, you can redefine the \subsection command (or any other sectioning command like \subsubsection, etc.) to do nothing. This will effectively hide these sections in the rendered document.
   `\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{}`
2. Or use a Conditional: If you want to switch between showing and hiding these sections without changing the LaTeX code each time, you can use a conditional command.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Define a new if condition
\newif\ifshowsubsections
% Enable or disable subsections here
\showsubsectionstrue  % or \showsubsectionsfalse

% Redefine subsection command based on the condition
\ifshowsubsections
  % If true, do nothing and use the default definition
\else
  % If false, redefine to do nothing
  \renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{}
\fi

\begin{document}

\section{Main Section}
This is the main section content.

\subsection{Subsection}
This subsection will be hidden if \textbackslash showsubsections is set to false.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I added this to my preamble. I just comment it out to get them back.

```
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{}
```

Comment: @Rusty Consider using the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701669/latex-ignore-subheaders/701671#comment1744829_701669 instead. This way you don't loose the ability to specify a short title in the sectioning commands.